# How to find overlapping cells of 2 matrices which are position centered of each other

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I want to find the overlapping cells of these 2 matrices in the image below. They both have the same cell size and they are position at the centered of each other like the image below.

And I also wondering how can I find the cells in 1 matrix that overlap 1 specific cell in the other matrix. I haven't figure out an algorithm to solve this yet can someone help give me some direction to solve this problem ?

Also is there an algorithm to solve this even if the matrices dimension are not set like the image below i.e. 4x5 and 5x4 matrices instead of 5x4 and 2x2 like the image below.

From the Image I posted Input is 2 2D array with size of [5.4] for the red matrix and [2,2] for the green matrix.

The first problem the output will have overlap position of those 2 matrix so for the red matrix it {(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2)} and the green matrix is all of its cell position

And for the second problem there will be an extra input which is the position of 1 specific cell on the red matrix for example (2,1) and the output will be the cells on the green matrix that overlap the cell we just pick in the red matrix so {(0,0), (1,0)}

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm just being obtuse, but I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give example input and output?

Comment: Do you mean [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing)?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by laying out the requirements in my own words, to make sure we're on the same page:

- We have two matrices, call them *A* and *B*, which may be of different sizes.
- We imagine them rendered as grids as in your image.

  - The image isn't an input to the algorithm or anything (we don't need image processing), it's just to illustrate how we imagine the matrices to be represented for purposes of deciding whether a cell in *A* "overlaps" with *B*.
  - The only inputs to the algorithm are the matrices themselves.
- We want to find the cells in *A* that overlap with *B*.
- Cells are identified as ordered pairs (*i*, *j*), using zero-based indices; for example, if *A* is an *m*<sub>*A*</sub>×*n*<sub>*A*</sub> matrix, then 0 ≤ *i* < *m*<sub>*A*</sub> and 0 ≤ *j* < *n*<sub>*A*</sub>.

We observe the following:

- There's a range of rows in *A* that overlap with *B*.
- There's a range of columns in *A* that overlap with *B*.
- A cell in *A* overlaps with *B* if it's in that range of rows and that range of columns.

Let's start with rows. If *A* has *m*<sub>*A*</sub> rows and *B* has *m*<sub>*B*</sub> rows, then we have three cases:

- If *m*<sub>*A*</sub> ≤ *m*<sub>*B*</sub>, then all rows of *A* overlap with *B*.
- Otherwise, if *m*<sub>*A*</sub> and *m*<sub>*B*</sub> are both even or both odd (that is: if *m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub> is even), then the rows of *A* and *B* line up properly; the first ½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>) rows of *A* are completely outside *B*, then one or more rows fit properly inside *B* (except for potentially sticking out on the left and right, of course), and then the last ½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>) rows are completely outside *B*.
- Otherwise, the rows of *A* and *B* are offset by ½; the first ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋ rows of *A* are completely outside *B*, then one row half-overlaps with *B*, then zero or more rows fit properly inside *B* (except for potentially sticking out on the left and right, of course), then another row half-overlaps with *B*, and then the last ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋ rows are completely outside *B*.

For our purposes, a row that half-overlaps with *B* is equivalent to a row that's fully inside *B*, in that we're equally interested in both; so we can actually combine the second and third cases into one:

- The first ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋ rows of *A* are completely outside *B*, then one or more rows overlap with *B*, and then the last ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋ rows are completely outside *B*.

where we've used the fact that, if *m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub> is even, then ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋ = ½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>).

And, in fact, we can even combine them with the very first case, like this:

- The first max(0, ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋) rows of *A* are completely outside *B*, then one or more rows overlap with *B*, and then the last max(0, ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋) rows are completely outside *B*.

If we regard the non-overlapping rows as forming "margins" at top and bottom (just so we have a convenient variable-name), we can write that like this:

*marginHeight* := max(0, ⌊½(*m*<sub>*A*</sub> − *m*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋)

Columns work the same way, so we don't need to repeat all that reasoning, we can just adapt the conclusion:

*marginWidth* := max(0, ⌊½(*n*<sub>*A*</sub> − *n*<sub>*B*</sub>)⌋)

Putting it together, we can write:

findOverlaps(*A*, *B*):
        *marginHeight* := max(0, ⌊½(*A*.height − *B*.height)⌋)
        *marginWidth* := max(0, ⌊½(*A*.width − *B*.width)⌋)
        *result* := new Set
        for *i* from *marginHeight* to *A*.height − *marginHeight* − 1:
            for *j* from *marginWidth* to *A*.width − *marginWidth* − 1:
                *result*.append((*i*, *j*))
        return *result*

Comment: Your interpretation of the requirements is correct. I'm sorry that I wasn't able to explain the problems properly